# Rails TimeHelpers travel_to with nanosecond not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

In my code I have `Time.current.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S%6N')`
and to test that I used the Rails TimeHelpers #travel_to method.

in the tests:

```
travel_to Time.local(2015, 2, 2, 11, 14, 30.123456) do
  ...
end
```

The problem is that `Time.current.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S%6N')` returns 000000 for nanoseconds when it should be 123456.

Is there a work around? I am trying not to use TimeCop gem at the moment.

Comment: That's expected. From the docs for [`travel_to`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/TimeHelpers.html#method-i-travel_to): _"Note that the usec for the time passed will be set to 0"_

Comment: Thank you @Stefan , you can answer this post and i'll tick your answer. It's a shame because it means i'll have to use timecop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, Rails' [`travel_to`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/TimeHelpers.html#method-i-travel_to) truncates the value to seconds. From the docs:

> Note that the usec for the time passed will be set to 0 to prevent rounding errors with external services, like MySQL (which will round instead of floor, leading to off-by-one-second errors).

As a workaround you could change your code to accept an explicit time with current time as its default:

```
def your_method(time = Time.current)
  time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S%6N')
end
```

And in your tests:

```
describe '#your_method' do
  context 'with an explicit time value' do
    let(:time) { Time.local(2015, 2, 2, 11, 14, 30.123456) }

    it 'generates the corresponding timestamp' do
      expect(your_method(time)).to eq('20150202111430123456')
    end
  end

  context 'without argument' do
    around do |example|
      travel_to(Time.local(2015, 2, 2, 11, 14)) { example.run }
    end

    it 'generates the current timestamp' do
      expect(your_method).to eq('20150202111400000000')
    end
  end
end
```